# How to show an alert in javascript when the countdown time is over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

This is my code for displaying countdown time for 1 minute on a HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 1;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
if (document.getElementById) {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining
    if (seconds < 59) {
        seconds.value = secs;
    } else {
        minutes.value = getminutes();
        seconds.value = getseconds();
    }
    secs--;
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
}
function getminutes() {
// minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
// take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;">m 
<input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">s
</body></html>
```

I want to show an alert message displaying "Time over" when the countdown reached to `0m 0s` and when the user click on `ok` button of the alert box, the page should be redirected to `example.html`. How can I achieve this?

Edit : I have done this way-

```
function Decrement() {
if (document.getElementById) {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    // if less than a minute remaining
    if (seconds < 59) {
        seconds.value = secs;
    } else {
        minutes.value = getminutes();
        seconds.value = getseconds();
    }

    if (minutes==0 && seconds==0){
        if (window.confirm('Time over'))
        {
            window.location="http://www.example.com";
        }
        else
        {
            window.location="http://www.example.com";
        }
    }
    secs--;
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
```

But it is not working. The counter goes negative instead of asking for conformation at 0m 0s. How to make it working?

Comment: It is actually `minutes.value==0` and `seconds.value==0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your timeout has exceeded you can call the confirm Function like this:

```
if (window.confirm('The countdown has ended. Redirect?'))
{
    // They clicked Yes
}
else
{
   // They clicked no
}
```

The further possibilities with this function are described here:

[Confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php)

So before you call the `setTimeout()` again in your `Decrement` function you can check if the minutes and seconds are zero and then call the confirm action. Otherwise, if this condition is not met you proceed with decrementing.

### Edit

You also had some errors in your JavaScript Code. I´ve done some improvements on it and you can look at it at this JsFiddle:

[Countdown](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ty9btj/)

First of all you´ve had a problem, because you´ve never set the minutes and the seconds back to the inputs. Next, you hadn´t closed the  Tags for the minutes and the seconds. I guess the setTimeout didn´t work either, because of the passed string. Often it´s better to use a full function expression in those cases. You can see the changes in the JsFiddle.

Comment: You´ve also got some further errors. I´ve prepared a jsfiddle for you: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ty9btj/)

Comment: Please review the edit in the question details and tell me why it is not working.

Comment: Np. You also have some problems with the decrement of your Minutes and seconds. Your minutes get decremented before the seconds are zero. In this jsfiddle is an updated version that should work properly: [Countdown](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ty9btj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `setInterval()`? Like the following:

```
var timeCount = setInterval(Decrement, 1000);

function Decrement() {
    if (secs === 0) {
        clearInterval(timeCount);
        return;
    }

    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
    }

    secs--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 0;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = 3;

var minutes, seconds;

function countdown() {
  setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}

function Decrement() {
    // if less than a minute remaining
    if (seconds < 59) {
        seconds.value = secs;
    } else {
        minutes.value = getminutes();
        seconds.value = getseconds();
    }
    secs--;

    console.log(minutes + ', ' + seconds);
    if (seconds.value <= 0 && minutes.value <= 0) {
          if (window.confirm('timeout')) {
        alert('done');
      } else {
        alert('nothing to do');
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}

function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return mins;
}

function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}

// It's necessary
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(document.readyState == "complete") {
    minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");

    countdown();
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;">m 
    <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">s
</body>
</html>
```